# Spotify API, cannot Chaining two API calls (Authorization-GetSong)

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, spotify

Simply I am trying to implement getting token from API and after that get a song with the token. Because of storing token in a global variable and after executing `getAuthorizationToken` asynchronously, `getSong` function is invoked immediately. Therefore, the API is called with value of undefined for the getting song and getting HTTP 401.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');

function getAuthorizationToken() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/', true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + Buffer.from(config.clientID + ":" + config.clientSecret).toString('base64'));
    request.onload = function () {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log(data['access_token']);
            authorizationToken = data['access_token'];
        }
    };
    request.send("grant_type=client_credentials");
}

function getSong() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + authorizationToken);
    request.onload = function () {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(data)
    };
   request.send();
}
getAuthorizatonToken();
getSong(); //this is invoked before authorizatonToken's value assigned.
```

I tried to use `Promise` for chaining like that;

```
function getAuthorizationToken() {

return new Promise(() => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/', true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + Buffer.from(config.clientID + ":" + config.clientSecret).toString('base64'));
    request.onload = function () {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log(data['access_token']);
            authorizationToken = data['access_token'];
        }
    };
    request.send("grant_type=client_credentials");
    });
}

function getSong() {
    // same method 
}

getAuthorizationToken().then(getSong);
```

However, it returns nothing for `getSong` function. I am not sure about that but I believe promise don't wait for `onload`.

Also, I tried to send first request synchronously, it gives an error;

> Error: Synchronous XHR processing not implemented

I am not familiar with coding on JavaScript, what is wrong with the way of my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your promise is you need to resolve or reject to exit from promise and pass the token data to the next promise or function.

A simple promise function looks like this:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});
```

Here is the final code:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');


function getAuthorizationToken() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/');
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + Buffer.from(config.clientID + ":" + config.clientSecret).toString('base64'));

        request.onload = function () {
            if (request.status === 200) {   
                let responseBody = JSON.parse(this.response);                              
                resolve(responseBody["access_token"]);
            }else{
                reject(request.status);
            }
        };
        request.onerror = function () {
            reject(Error("Network Error"));
        };
        request.send("grant_type=client_credentials");
    });

}

function getSong(authorizationToken) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + authorizationToken);
        request.onload = function () {
            if (request.status === 200) {   
                let responseBody = JSON.parse(this.response);                              
                resolve(responseBody);
            }else{
                reject(request.status);
            }
        };
        request.onerror = function () {
            reject(Error("Network Error"));
        };
        request.send();
    });
}

getAuthorizationToken().then(function (authorizationToken) {
    getSong(authorizationToken).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);        
    })
});
```